# told me about the way

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

a. He told me how he was arrested.

---

b. He told me about how he was arrested.

c. He told me the way he was arrested.

d.He told me about the way he was arrested.

I know (a) could have two meanings. It could either mean he told me the manner in which he was arrested and also he told me that he was arrested.

But how about (b), (c) and (d)?

Are they ambiguous as well, or do they only have the manner interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

They all convey the same meaning, but they are quite odd sentences to use.

> "the way" = "how"

Although b, c and d do have a overa difference compared to a

> (B), (c) and (d) specifically refer to the manner in which the person was arrested. It would not normally be expressed that way unless there was something unusual about the method of arrest that needed to be explained.

^ @KateBunting

Comment: Thank you so much. So to you none of the sentences is ambiguous, right? I feel that (a) is ambiguous.

Comment: @azz yes I think all are fine and not ambigious they are all nearly the same thing!

Comment: (B), (c) and (d) specifically refer to the manner in which the person was arrested. It would not normally be expressed that way unless there was something unusual about the method of arrest that needed to be explained.